# Confused about using the Zabbix Template MySQL (800+ items)

Tags: perl, mysql, monitoring, zabbix

Please explain the full use of this template.[link template](https://share.zabbix.com/databases/mysql/template-mysql-800-items)

I searched very much on Google, I have configured as described but i can't use this yet.
Can you fully explain? 
i have two centos 7. zabbix version 3.4.
config zabbix-agent:
`/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_mysql.conf`

```
UserParameter=mysql.status[*],echo "show global status where Variable_name='$1';" | HOME=/etc/zabbix mysql -N | awk '{print $$2}'

UserParameter=mysql.size[*],bash -c 'echo "select sum($(case "$3" in both|"") echo "data_length+index_length";; data|index) echo "$3_length";; free) echo "data_free";; esac)) from information_schema.tables$([[ "$1" = "all" || ! "$1" ]] || echo " where table_schema=\"$1\"")$([[ "$2" = "all" || ! "$2" ]] || echo "and table_name=\"$2\"");" | HOME=/etc/zabbix mysql -N'

UserParameter=mysql.ping,HOME=/etc/zabbix mysqladmin ping | grep -c alive
UserParameter=mysql.version,mysql -V
UserParameter=mysql[*],/etc/zabbix/mysql_check.pl $1 $2 $3 $4
```

i create user `mysql`.

```
CREATE USER 'david'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'david123';
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
MariaDB [(none)]> select user,host from mysql.user;
+--------------+-----------+
| user         | host      |
+--------------+-----------+
| cluster_user | %         |
| david        | %         |
| dav          | 127.0.0.1 |
| root         | 127.0.0.1 |
| root         | ::1       |
| dav          | db1       |
| root         | db1       |
| root         | db3       |
| dav          | localhost |
| fazeli       | localhost |
| root         | localhost |
+--------------+-----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
------------------------------------------------
     MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;           
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
    ------------------------------------------------
    MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'david'@'%';  
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for david@%                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'david'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*76E1DED67C484EF41716EFA3545C12098380B713' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
------------------------------------------------
```

i create `.my.cnf` in `/etc/zabbix`

```
[mysql]
user=david
password=david123
[mysqladmin]
user=david
password=david123
```

my `perl` script `mysql_check.pl` on `/etc/zabbix`

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;
my $user = shift;
my $password = shift;
my $type = shift;
my $search_like = shift;
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=mysql;host=db2";
my $tmp_file = '/tmp/zbx_mysql.status';
my $zbx_sender_file = '/usr/bin/zabbix_sender';
my $zabbix_sender = '/usr/bin/zabbix_sender';
```

i set macro.(look screenshot).

[image: macro-1]
[image: macro-2]

permission files:

```
[root@db2 zabbix]# ll
total 92
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 78654 Jan 24 06:20 mysql_check.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11124 Jan 21 10:28 zabbix_agentd.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    38 Jan 21 09:52 zabbix_agentd.d
```

PLEASE.THANKS.

Comment: What zabbix version do you use? What steps you have been completed?

Comment: one obvious error is that the string `dav`  in `mysql_check.pl` needs to be quoted: `my $user = 'dav';`.  don't know much about zabbix so can't help beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** if your screenshot included the actual root password for your MySQL database, please change it as soon as possible!

This UserParameter line suggests that `mysql_check.pl` takes four parameters that are probably specified by the template:

```
UserParameter=mysql[*],/etc/zabbix/mysql_check.pl $1 $2 $3 $4
```

The original `mysql_check.pl` that comes with the template has this in the beginning:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;

my $user = shift;
my $password = shift;

my $type = shift;

my $search_like = shift;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=mysql;host=<replace mysql host>";
my $tmp_file = '/tmp/zbx_mysql.status';
my $zbx_sender_file = '/tmp/zbx_mysql.sender';

[...continues...]
```

I assume that you've posted only the important/edited lines of this part in your question. I see two problems:

1.) the lack of proper quoting that was also noted by cas:

> one obvious error is that the string dav in mysql_check.pl needs to be quoted: my $user = 'dav';. don't know much about zabbix so can't help beyond that. – cas

I assume you already fixed this.

2.) the four `shift` commands are supposed to pick the command line parameters received by `mysql_check.pl` and place them into variables, in order.

In the original version, the first parameter gets stored to variable `$user`, the second to `$password`, and so on. But you've replaced the first two of the `shift` commands with hard-coded values: this will cause the first parameter (which apparently is the MySQL username from your screenshotted macro, passed through the template) to be assigned to `$type` instead of `$user`, and the password to `$search_like` instead of `$password`. The 3rd and 4th command line parameters will be left unused. And those two parameters would tell the `mysql_check.pl` what to check.

Looking further into the `mysql_check.pl` script code, your modified version of it will end up doing nonsensical things because it's trying to interpret the username as the `$type` value, so it will return either nothing at all or something the template won't be able to parse.

Don't remove any `shift` commands from `mysql_check.pl`. If you need to hard-code the username and password for some reason, do it like this:

```
[...]
use DBI;

my $user = shift;
my $password = shift;

#hard-coded user info for testing only; these should come from the zabbix macro instead
$user = 'dav';
$password = 'dav123456';

my $type = shift; 
my $search_like = shift;
[...]
```

Also, it looks like your Zabbix macros `${MYSQL_USER}` and `${MYSQL_PWD}` have the values 'dav' and 'dav123456' respectively assigned at the global level, but 'root' and '' at the host level. The host-level assignments will override the global ones, so the template will be using the wrong values.

Comment: thanks a lot telcoM for your time. i edit everything(`mysql_user`,`database`,`maysql_check.pl` to `default`). and set macro again. but i don't receive any data yet. please look again my config.