# zabbix_sender error

Tags: perl, mysql, monitoring, zabbix

What is the meaning of this error?

```
[root@db2 zabbix]# zabbix_sender -z zabbix -s zabbix -k mysql[Threads_running] -o 100 -vv               
zabbix_sender [55944]: DEBUG: answer [{"response":"success","info":"processed: 0; failed: 1; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.000015"}]
info from server: "processed: 0; failed: 1; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.000015"
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1
[root@db2 zabbix]#
```

Also [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419324/confused-about-using-the-zabbix-template-mysql-800-items) i explin completly my config and issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that server did not accept the value. Common reasons:

- incorrect hostname
- incorrect item key
- item not in the server configuration cache yet

Note that hostnames and item keys are case sensitive.

Comment: My problem was with the hostname.