# zabbix template mysql (800+item)

Tags: perl, mysql, monitoring, zabbix

I use this template. [template-mysql-800-items](https://share.zabbix.com/databases/mysql/template-mysql-800-items)

when i send parameter by this command

`zabbix_sender -z zabbix -s db1 -k mysql[innodb_queries_inside] -o 100 -vv`

On zabbix server i can see result.

[image: zabbix_latest_data]

but when execute another command I do not receive any result. example :

`mysqlslap --user=root --password --host=db1 --concurrency=100 --iterations=100 --auto-generate-sql --verbose`

Why is not sending the request in the usual mode of information in the zabbix?

Comment: Have you configured the mysql_check.pl script that comes with the template with the correct database parameters?

Comment: yes telcom. please look this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419324/confused-about-using-the-zabbix-template-mysql-800-items).

Comment: I answered at that other question. If you have the same errors in the `mysql_check.pl` here as well, no wonder it does not work.